# Питон Как получить строку '\x'?

Tags: python, экранирование, micropython

Задача
есть строка байт in_string в hex формате без разделителей типа AABBCCDDEEFF
необходимо преобразовать в \xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF
Не могу получить строку `\x` чтобы ее вставить в исходную
Вместо нее вставляется `\\x`
Я пробовал разные варианты

```
for i in range (0, len(in_string),2): text=text+'\\x'+in_string[i:i+2]
for i in range (0, len(in_string),2): text=text+r'\x'+in_string[i:i+2]
for i in range (0, len(in_string),2): text=text+'\x5Cx'+in_string[i:i+2]
```

Результат всегда `\\xAA\\xBB\\xCC\\xDD\\xEE\\xFF`

Comment: А что дальше будет происходить с этой строкой? Может, лучше сразу в массив байт это все?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может имелось в виду всё же преобразование в байты?

```py
data = bytes.fromhex("AABBCCDDEEFF")
print(data)
```

Вывод:

```
b'\xaa\xbb\xcc\xdd\xee\xff'
```

Comment: Пишу на MicroPython v1.18-23-g7d71ae25e а там AttributeError: type object 'bytes' has no attribute 'fromhex'

Comment: @MBU, то что MicroPython используете - это нужно в вопросе указывать.

Comment: @MBU на micropython должно работать `import binascii` `binascii.unhexlify("AABBCCDDEEFF")`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjmDP.png (идея отсюда https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=7949)

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо. Извиняюсь сразу не указал про микропитон

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так:

```
in_string = 'AABBCCDDEEFF'
text = ''
for i in range (0, len(in_string),2):
    text=text+'\\x'+in_string[i:i+2]
print(text)
```

Ответ:

```
\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF
```